# Is there a SEO or UX reason against not adding a contact page?

Tags: seo, page, ux, contact-page

I am an amateur website-builder. But I am, as far as possible, trying to do it right the first time.

My client is a restaurant and B&B and they want to keep the main navigation as small as possible. So I added just 3 navigation items (assortment / B&B / about), each consisting of drop-down lists.

Now I could make 3 small pages: about (head), contact (sub), opening-hours (sub) or I could just make one page with all the information in different sections. I could than add anchors to those sections and link my drop-down-items to these anchors.

Is there any reason why this is not a good idea?

Comment: For a restaurant, hours, address, and phone are so important that they should be on *every* page.  They don't take up much room and they can usually be incorporated into the header.

Answer (score 1):

I've read that Google gives websites a small ranking boost for having a contact page, an about us page and a privacy policy page. It makes your site more official and customer friendly. I think it's better to have all 3 on separate pages for this reason.

You can link to the other 2 pages from each of those pages so that it's easy to navigate. You can also add a way to contact you on the about us page.

Answer (score 1):

Either design should be fine. We are talking a total of 6 lines for Contact and opening-hours section, and About is a variable -- in other words, it's not a lot of content that'll tilt the balance significantly.

That said, for a restaurant, local SEO is more important where you can enter contact info, hours, images etc., and also get verified. It becomes more important if it's a new restaurant.

https://www.google.com/business/